# mysql date search using timestamp

Tags: mysql, date

how do i search dates using mysql.
Database fields are like this:

### date

Monday, 21 December 2009 11:54:16

### timeurl

1261376656

I have date text field: '21/12/2009'

how do i search date in the database. 'date' field type is varchar and timeurl type is timestamp

thanks

Comment: date type is varchar and timeurl is timestamp

Comment: Fix your table to store dates with the data type `date`. Never ever store dates as text.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about the date format you need to enter in your query it's:

For queries on a `DATE` column you should enter dates with format `'yyyy-MM-dd'`.

For queries on a `TIMESTAMP` or `DATETIME` columns you should enter dates with format `'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'`

MySql is very flexible on this - you can actually use many other formats for insertion and querying as described [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html).